# Wireless problems on HP Mini 1103 with Windows 7 32-bit installed

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dns, hp-mini

I have a brand new laptop (HP Mini) whose wireless connection continuously drops for some unknown reason.  The only way of reconnecting to the WiFi is to restart the machine.  This problem happens at random and it doesn't matter what we're doing on the machine.

Meanwhile, we have other laptops nearby that connect to the wireless access point perfectly fine. I took it to a different building on campus and the problem persists. I checked the Event Logs and found warnings stating that "WLAN autoconfig service has successfully stopped" followed by a DNS error.

I've updated the wireless card drivers (Ralink card), ran Windows Update, changed power management settings on the card, ran virus/spyware scans, but with no success.  The problem remains.

What can I do?

Comment: Is it the 110 or 210 mini?

Answer (score 0):

[See this page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02543015&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en#N2575), go down to section "Slow or dropped wireless connections" for more troubleshooting tips.

If those tips don't help, uninstall the HP Wireless Assistant and reboot, let windows manage the wireless connections, see if things improve any.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions; however, I'm in college campus and they don't exactly inform us of the physical location of the routers.